# The probability that the amount of marbles (totally 2500) randomly tossed in five boxes will be no less than 490 in one specific box.

Tags: probability, gaussian-integral

The mean is 500. So, I am using Gaussian integral whose values are already calculated in table. $$F\left(\frac{2500-2500}{20}\right) - F\left(\frac{490 - 500}{20}\right)= 0 + 0,5 - F(0,5) = 0,5 - 0,1915 = 0,3175.$$. I think I may be wrong when regarding the first part of the equation. Should I add to the zero 0,5?

Comment: This is almost identical to your previous question.  The end result is that your table is giving you values for the area between the center of the bell curve to your specified point.  Recognize, the expected amount of marbles in the box is $500$, so it stands to reason that we might expect about half of the time that the amount of marbles in that box would be greater than $500$.  It stands to reason then that more than half the time the number of marbles in that box would be bigger than $490$

Comment: You should have added to $0.5$ rather than subtracted from it.  The result you should have gotten should have been $Pr(Z>\frac{490-500}{20})\approx 0.691462$ without a continuity correction, or as before a continuity correction is quite helpful here giving an answer of [$Pr(Z>\frac{489.5-500}{20})\approx 0.700208$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Pr%28Z%3E%28489.5-500%29%2F20%29) which is closer to the [true value of $\approx 0.698942$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+from+n%3D490+to+2500+of+%282500+choose+n%290.2%5En*0.8%5E%282500-n%29)

Comment: @JMoravitz I subtracted $F(0,5)$ from $0,5$ because the value $z$ is negative in this instance. I've read that in such instances you should subtract not add from 0,5.

Comment: You need to spend some time to understand what your function $F$ represents in terms of areas under the curve and spend some time understanding how the various areas under the curve relate to one another.  $Pr(Z>-0.5) = Pr(-0.5<Z<0)+Pr(Z\geq 0)$ for instance.  Your table seems to be giving values of the form $F(x)=Pr(0\leq Z<x)$.  You might also have gotten confused between the phrase "no less" and "less".  A value being no less than $490$ means it is $490$ or greater.

Comment: @JMoravitz Ok, but in this instance $F\right(\frac{490-500}{20}\right)$ is negative value, so I don't understand why we need to add 0,5. Maybe you know any source where one can read about this specific problem?

Comment: See a video like [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-UljIcq_rfc) vs [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dwRVY0FjpQM).  Take careful note of the fact that there are many different ways in which tables can be written.  Some are written giving values of $Pr(Z\leq z)$, others are written giving values of $Pr(0\leq Z\leq z)$.  Recognize that for positive $z$ we have $Pr(Z\leq z) = Pr(Z\leq 0) + Pr(0\leq Z\leq z) = 0.5 + Pr(0\leq Z\leq z)$ and similar.  The end result is again that you need to understand what your entries in your table represent in terms of areas under a curve.

Comment: @JMoravitz Thank you Moravitz, the videos were really helpful. So, for this my solution would be $1 - F(0,5) = 1 - 0,1915 = 0,8075$.

Comment: @JMoravitz But still, when I try to calculate the probability that $P(490 \le m \le 523$ I kind of fail. I assume that I should simply add F(0,5) + F(1,15), but in that case the area is greater than 1. ( If I am using the table where the area between 0 and $z$ is used.)

Comment: Do what the video suggest and *draw a picture* to organize your thoughts.  No, it will not be $0.8075$.  You do not subtract $0.1915$.  We were trying to find $Pr(Z>-0.5)$ which by symmetry is $Pr(Z<0.5)$ which we know to be $Pr(Z\leq 0) + Pr(0\leq Z<0.5)$ which we know the first part of which to be $0.5$ and the second part of which can be found in our table as $\approx 0.1915$, so as I had alluded to in my comments two hours ago would give an answer of $\approx 0.6915$

Comment: @JMoravitz, Yes, that makes total sense. Then $P(490 \le m \le 523)=0,1915+0,3749=0,5664.$ But then, I had to calculate the probability that the amount of marbles will be exactly the mean, i.e., 500, and as I understand, the probability would be zero, right?

Comment: It would be **near** zero.  You still aren't using the continuity correction.  Without the continuity correction, you might have said it was exactly zero but it should be obvious that it is *possible* and hence positive probability to get exactly 500 marbles.  With continuity correction you'd have gotten $P(\frac{499.5-500}{20}\leq Z\leq \frac{500.5-500}{20})\approx 0.019945$, much closer to the exact value of $\binom{2500}{500}\times 0.2^{500}\times 0.8^{2000}\approx 0.0199436$